# how to send data to the internet HTTP Post request using flutter ( fixed )

Tags: json, flutter, post

**FIXED, CHECK THE CODE IN MY OWN ANSWER BELOW**

Hello dear Stackoverflow community, i'm kinda new to flutter and i can't really understand this problem i'm getting while trying to send a post request from the flutter app

```
_CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)
```

here is my code

```
sendForm() async {
  var jsonResponse;
  // the error line is below, in the http method
  var response = await http.post(
    "https://promoteur-api.herokuapp.com/api/messages",
    body: {
      // update
      // the problem is in the message":{...} it makes it Map<String, String> instead of String
      "message": {
        "nom": nomController.text,
        "prenom": prenomController.text,
        "tel": telController.text,
        "email": emailController.text,
        "sujet": sujetController.text,
        "message": messageController.text
      }
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if (jsonResponse != null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  } else {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

and i'm calling the method here

```
 onPressed: () {
   sendForm();
 },
```

here is the request in postman :

```
{
   "message": {
     "nom": "Testing name",
     "prenom": "Testing name",
     "tel": "25252525",
     "email": "testing@gmail.com",
     "sujet": "Testing subject",
     "message": "something here"
   }
}
```

and the response :

```
{
"id": 6,
"nom": "Testing name",
"prenom": "Testing name",
"tel": 25252525,
"email": "testing@gmail.com",
"sujet": "Testing subject",
"message": "something here"
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the line print(response.body); Instead try print(response['body']);

Comment: nah it's definitively no the cause of it, the problem is in the line `"message": { ... } ` it makes it Map<String, String> instead of String, trying to find a way to fix it but couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

Might look frightening but _InternalLinkedHashMap is just the internal LinkedHashMap class which is just the default Map implementation.

Somewhere in your code you must have wrongly placed a map object into a string type parameter.

Because the only statically typed part of your `sendForm` function is the function parameters itself I think you have passed a Map object to it. -> maybe check what you passed to that function :)

Comment: the problem is in the message": { ... } it makes it Map<String, String> instead of String, trying to find a way to fix it but couldn't find any

Comment: try to declare generic types on `Map data` or `Map body` also statically type the responseJson object and you may find your type error

Comment: there is no error right now with that code it works perfectly u can as well check my answer down below